# Maya Mel : Enable or disable button or change background color by another button

Tags: 3d, maya, mel

How to enable or disable button or change button background color by another button in maya mel.
This my code so far.

```
global string $btn2;

global proc fun(string $btn){
    button -label "button 2" -enable false $btn;
} 
window -width 150;
columnLayout -adjustableColumn true;
    $btn1 = `button -label "button 1" -c "fun $btn2"`;
    $btn2 = `button -label "button 2" -enable true`;
showWindow;
```

Comment: What research have you done so far. Do you have any code that you ve written so far.

Comment: [mel documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/Commands/button.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that will work:

```
button "button_name" -edit "True" -backgroundColor "float float float" -enable "boolean";
```

replace `button_name` with the name of your button. Replace `float float float` with float values of the RGB color values egs. `"1.0 0.0 0.0"` for red.

Comment: Please consider giving explanations to your code, as I have editted your answer. Also please make sure your answer is properly formatted to maintain the quality of this community.